# Remove Windows Live

Tags: windows-vista

Is there anyway to remove windows live and all the other windows products that I don't use from my computer without making vista go crazy?

Comment: How exactly is Windows going crazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the software such as Photo Gallery, Movie Maker, Messenger, Mail, etc?

Start > Control Panel > Program and Features

On the side bar is an option to "Turn Windows features on or off"
Here you can disable Gadgets and Games, and under Media Features are options for Media Centre, DVD maker and Media player.

Photo Gallery, Movie Maker, Messenger, Mail may be listed here in Vista. I'm on Windows 7 so I can't be sure. (These programs are not included in Win7)

Answer (score 5):

Windows Live is just a program, just as any other program. You can remove it in the software configuration screen.

And what other windows products do you mean?

Comment: All of the software the comes pre-installed that starts with "windows"

Comment: And when I have tried to just uninstall it, Vista said I need admin and then said I didn't have the proper premissions

Comment: Are you sure you're logging in with an admin account?

Comment: You might want to try the pcdecrapifier http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/ for a simple solution once you have your admin authority

Answer (score 2):

Try [sysinternals autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to turn stuff off when booting and see if it affects anything, then you can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the PC Decrapifier at http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/.